# FTDI chip detection issue

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ftdi

I'm trying to do some transactions over serial ftdi interface to an ARM based board. On windows i'm able to detect it but when from virtualbox i'm unable to detect the same.
When i connect the same board to a linux sever box, it gets detected and gives me the port /dev/ttyuSB0. Any idea why Virtualbox does not detect?

Comment: This is an old link, but it might help point you in the right direction: [How to pass through USB devices to guest on Ubuntu 8.10](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualbox-2-how-to-pass-through-usb-devices-to-guests-on-an-ubuntu-8.10-host)

Comment: You can try out vmware workstation and give it a try perhaps virtualbox has some problems with usb detection https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/3041

Answer (score 0):

By default, your VMs in VirtualBox can't see any of your 'real' hardware. You can "move" a USB device from the host to the guest. (Appears as a disconnect from the host, then a connect to the guest), but it's an odd two-step process:

- When the VM isn't running, create a USB "filter" on your device.
- Then, when it's running, sometimes it grabs it, and sometimes you must click the USB icon (at the bottom of your running VM window, next to your disk/CD/mouse indicators).

Make sure you have a recent version of VirtualBox. I think before 4.x, the USB support was not included in the free version.  But I can confirm it works in 4.1.

Comment: in 5.0.24 filters do not help. virtualbox usb extension pack also does not help. the /dev/ttyUSB0 remains in the host but not in guest, doesn't show up in device list and doesn't show up on guest lsusb